# Полное отключение вибрации при звонке

Tags: android

Необходимо отключить вибрацию при звонке.
Пробовал:

1) через AudioManager

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setVibrateSetting(AudioManager.VIBRATE_TYPE_RINGER, AudioManager.VIBRATE_SETTING_OFF);
```

Метод устарел (@deprecated). Код запускается, вибрация не исчезает.

2) через Vibrator

```
 Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
 vibrator.cancel();
```

Не работает.

3) через установку беззвучного режима

```
audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

Звук убирается, вибрация остается.

4) через установку громкости с флагом FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE

```
    audioManager = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
            ringStreamMinVolume = audioManager.getStreamMinVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING);
        } else {
            ringStreamMinVolume = 0;
        }
    audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, ringStreamMinVolume, AudioManager.FLAG_REMOVE_SOUND_AND_VIBRATE);
```

Тоже убирает только звук.

Тестировал на xiaomi redmi 4x. Android 6.0.1 MMB29M. Оболочка MIUI Global 8.2 Стабильная 8.2.9.0(MAMMIEA).

Третий пункт похоже связан с особенностями устройства - полной беззвучки как таковой нет, вибрацию надо отключать отдельно. Но хочется, чтобы работало и с такими особенностями.

Вопрос: как отключить вибрацию при звонке?